# Safari video element initial playback takes longer than chrome/firefox/edge

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video

I have a video element which I'm controlling the full screen and play via a dedicated button. Otherwise the video element is hidden.

```
<video controls>
    <source src="/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<button>play</button>
```

Plays fine. However, the initial playback on Safari 13 Catalina takes an additional few seconds over other browsers. Checking the network tab doesn't reveal any pre-loading. It seems Safari has a higher buffer threshold before playing.

Is there a workaround for this behavior?

Comment: is the MP4 encoded with the MOOV atom at the start of the file? - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537770/safari-videos-load-far-too-slowly/53547419#53547419

Answer (score 0):

Setting preload="auto" on the video tag should make the video seem to start faster, if you are not concerned with extra bandwidth.

A further optimization would be to try serving an HLS stream in addition to the progressive download mp4.  You don't need a special server to do this, a conventional web server can serve HLS live streams if they are correctly encoded/packaged.