# Fullscreen Video for Website Background Take long Time to Load in Website

Tags: php, html, css, video, video-streaming

I am building a fullscreen video for my website background that is autoplay and loop all the time. it is working well, but it takes a long time (around 3 min) to load the video.

the video is 9 MB and 1280 * 720. I tried to compress the video with many online websites but still the same problem and it affects the resolution of the video.

I am using HTML5 and programming with PHP.  here is the code:

```
 <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="/media/video/poster.png">
    <source src="/media/video/test.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="/media/video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/media/video/test.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

If you know another programming technique that could help me achieve my goal, I appreciate your help.

Comment: have you also made sure the MOOV element is at the start of the mp4? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537770/safari-videos-load-far-too-slowly/53547419#53547419

Answer (score 1):

Place the muted attribute before the autoplay attribute like so:

```
<video playsinline muted autoplay loop poster="/media/video/poster.png">
    <source src="/media/video/test.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="/media/video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/media/video/test.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

This will greatly reduce your loading time as the audio has to be muted in order to autoplay (in IOS/Safari in particular) See [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=autoplay).

Hope this helps