# Video not playing on apple devices on first load

Tags: html, video, meteor, meteor-blaze

So I've looked over the apple docs and checked that my video will play inline (I am storing the video on s3).

My video on https://themobilecigarlounge.com will play on all devices and browsers with the exception of apple. It will play but not until you click a link and then go back to the homepage.

```
<video class="video-background" id="backgroundVideo" playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted"
        loop="loop">
        <source src="https://cigarlounge.s3.amazonaws.com/Cigar-Rolling-Suit-medium-new.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="https://cigarlounge.s3.amazonaws.com/Cigar-Rolling-Suit-medium.mov" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
```

Is the code I am inserting it with. What am I missing here? I have all the tags, I stripped the video of its audio track and I have it muted.

Comment: not sure if it will impact, but the `autoplay` etc switches ... if present then true, if not present then false (so `="autoplay"` etc are redundant). Is the mp4 video optimized so that the MOOV atom is at the start (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537770/safari-videos-load-far-too-slowly/53547419#53547419) as if not may be loading too slowly over the network to get all it needs to play

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with the Meteor framework I was using. I do not understand the root of the problem but it is some sort of rendering issue. I noticed where in one site this function was working perfectly the <video> tag was within a {{#if}} helper.

So I experimented and put the video within an if block that became true 100ms after the page rendered.... This solved the problem but seems hacky. Seems to be some sort of issue with the blaze templates rendering.