# <video> I can't advance video in progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, video, progress

I have the following code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" id=testing controls src="http://pruebas.migranhistoria.com/yt" autobuffer="true" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

in:

```
src="http://pruebas.migranhistoria.com/yt"
```

is a php code that downloads a video from youtube in mp4 format.

when executing the code, the video does play, but it does not allow me to go ahead with the cursor in the progress bar.

```html
Example, try to go to minute 10, it is not possible to advance. can anybody help me?
<video width="320" height="240" id=testing controls src="http://pruebas.migranhistoria.com/yt" autobuffer="true" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Comment: move you encoded the MP4 with the MOOV atom at the start of the file? this gives the browser all the metadata it needs to 'scrub' the video (assuming your server also supports byte range requests to allow it to download chunks rather than the wait for the whole file) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537770/safari-videos-load-far-too-slowly/53547419#53547419