# video progress bar is not working when I use python server

Tags: javascript, python, html, html5-video, python-server-pages

I am creating a web page like Youtube, the upload works but when showing the page to see the downloaded video and wanting to go to a specific position using the progress bar of the video controls, it restarts from scratch again, unless it loads all the metadata and restart the page, I use django to create the page but also if I use a static page like this:

```
<body>
<video controls preload width="640" height="360">
      <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</body>
```

and then run the command :

```
python -m http.server 5000
```

it does not work for me either

I try changing the time using

```
video.currentTime = 14;
```

in javascript but it causes an error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0uF6.png)

Comment: you need to optimize video for streaming - position the MOOV atom at the start of the video (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537770/safari-videos-load-far-too-slowly/53547419#53547419), and have a server that supports byte range requests.

Comment: It didn't work for me, and it also takes a long time if the file is very large and of high quality