# HTML5 video loading slow

Tags: html, html5-video

I have videos on my website that are taking very long to load.

I don't think it is my webhost **since it also happens on localhost.**
Each time there is only 1 video shown to the user, depending which category they chose. (So it is not loading each video always).

The videos that take longer to load are the bigger ones (the biggest one is about 351MB video file)

This is my html code for the video:

```
<div class='video'><h2>$vidTitle</h2><video width='640' height='360' controls preload='metadata'><source src='$viddir' type='video/mp4'></video></div>
```

I've also read that it could be that the video indexing could be at the end, could this be the case?

What can I do about this, do I need to use another player thann the default html5 player (I tried this but it didn't really help) | do I need to use a cdn?

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53547419/1569675 - will want to make sure the metadata is at the start of the video. Also be aware you can only have a certain number of connections to a domain concurrently, so might need to stagger the loading (use javascript to set the source for each in turn)

Comment: Yeah, I have reencoded each and every video with handbrake, this helped a bit but it still isn't optimal

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the preload='metadata' attribute in your video element is supposed to prevent the video from loading.
You could try preload='none' to test. I know that works.
As always, a good place to check is MDN web docs:

[mdn web docs : The Video Embed element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: Hey I just tried preload='none', but I get no difference in loading times/buffering.

I also checked the mdn web docs already but I don't really know what could help me there.

Thanks, regards

Answer (score 0):

`preload='metadata'` worked great for me video loads instantly (was taking about 8 seconds)