# Loop html video player with high precision

Tags: html, reactjs

We are building the website with the video player. Users can select the text that has a start and end time range in the video, and we need to loop the video in that exact time range. However, I am struggling to find a reliable approach or component to support this seemingly basic task.

Approaches that we tried:

1. onTimeUpdate callback - way too slow to be precise
2. setInterval - better, and more precise, but yet 30-50 milliseconds late.
3. src={video.source.url + "#t=start_time,end_time"} - works perfectly with timing limits, but there is no way to loop inside of start_time and end_time.

Has anyone dealt with similar task, has any ideas how to achieve this or interested in pair programming?

Comment: Have you ensured the video is appropriately optimized for seeking? See [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74358377/215552) and [its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74368213/215552) for more.

Comment: Hi, thank you, the suggestion in that q is related to `timeupdate` event, and this was my first approach to addressing this, unfortunately it is not precise enough. My looping capabilities work very well, once I am able to detect that the player has reached the end of the time range.